Java and PlantUML: wrong extension `.latex`
I am using Ubuntu 24 and trying to compile the following temp.tex file with the plantuml package (for testing purposes only):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{plantuml}

\begin{document}

Here is a UML diagram generated directly in LaTeX using Plant UML:

\begin{plantuml}
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: Test
Bobs --> Alice: Answer
@enduml
\end{plantuml}

\end{document}

To compile files with the plantuml package you need to use lualatex with the -shell-escape option:
dns@dns-pc:~/Downloads$ lualatex --synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape temp.tex

However, java uses the -tlatex:nopreamble option by default which generates files with a .latex extension that lualatex does not recognize.
Here's an example of the error output:
...
Executing PlantUML... 
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/plantuml/plantuml.jar -charset UT
F-8 -tlatex:nopreamble temp-plantuml.txt

! LaTeX Error: File `temp-plantuml.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.

There are several ways to work around this issue, but I want java to use the -ttex:nopreamble option by default and generate files with the .tex extension.

After the unsuccessful compilation with lualatex a file will be generated: temp-plantuml.latex. You can fix it manually in the terminal just by changing the extension of this file from .latex to .tex and compiling with lualatexagain.

Imho this has been corrected at least on the github of the plantuml package. Get the newest version from there.

Before this issue was posted, the GitHub file had already been downloaded, edited in several files by changing latex to tex, and it still didn't work:
https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/blob/83a4bfbdb398ee2e15657c77e80d142321b89d16/src/net/sourceforge/plantuml/OptionPrint.java#L144

you should not edit anything, but get the newest version of the LaTeX package from https://github.com/koppor/plantuml

I found a simpler work around solution. When the error appears and asks for Enter file name:, you type the name of the file with the extension latex and press ENTER and it works just as well.

Download plantuml.1.2023.jar from [1] and put it in place of plantuml.jar.
sudo apt install plantuml
export $PLANTUML_JAR=/usr/share/plantuml/plantuml
sudo cp ~/Programs/plantuml.1.2023.7.jar /usr/share/plantuml/plantuml.jar 

Source:
[1] https://sourceforge.net/projects/plantuml/
[2] https://github.com/koppor/plantuml/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file
[3] Thanks @UlrikeFischer.
